# Is it possible to forward 2 requests from 2 different servlets to 1 jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I was trying to do this in my servlet:

```
        Date date = new Date();
        request.setAttribute("status", status);
        request.setAttribute("date", date);
        if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("Incorrect password")|| status.equalsIgnoreCase("Username not found")) {
            request.getRequestDispatcher("error.jsp").forward(request,response);
        }
        else {
            request.getRequestDispatcher("success.jsp").forward(request,response);
        }
```

and this inside my success.jsp:

```
<%  
    String stat = (String) request.getAttribute("status"); 
    String timestamp = (String) request.getAttribute("date"); 
%>
    <p>Welcome, <%= stat %>! </p>
    <p>TimeStamp : <%= timestamp %> </p>
```

I got a 500 internal server error from the code above then I decided to use a separate servlet for my date object and forwarded the request to the same jsp but the I got a null value after this.

Why is it that my first implementation got a 500 internal server error and how come I got a null value on my second implementation? How can I solve this?

Comment: your first code looks good, the `500` means server error, which means there is an exception, please update the question and add the stacktrace yougot from the error, it could be in the JSP not in the servlet too. **side note** in an invalid login status, it's not good to specify what was the problem (wrong username, or wrong password) this will make an attacker job easier as attacker will now focus on 1 parameter, just use a general message, ex, `Invalid Login Info` or `Login failed, incorrect credentials`...

Comment: @Yazan It was a ClassCastException and I was able to fix it by using String.valueOf() with my date object but now I am getting a null value in my jsp instead.

edit: I was able to fix it completely. Thanks for the tips and help :)

Comment: null value for what? status or date? and which code are you using now? the one in thi question or something else (update the question with ur latest code)